# Filtering with multi field in django orm

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have some fields that I can use them for filtering a list. I can use all of this fields or some of them in filter query. MY view is like below. But I can not get a right answer. It means that some records that I expect to have been selected are not selected.

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):

serializer_class = serializers.UserListSerializer
pagination_class = AdminPagination
permission_classes = (IsAuthRolePermission,)

filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
ordering_fields = '__all__'


def get_queryset(self):

    full_name     = self.request.query_params.get('full_name', '')
    email         = self.request.query_params.get('email', '')
    facility_name = self.request.query_params.get('facility_name', '')
    user_state    = self.request.query_params.get('user_state', '')

    if full_name or email or facility_name or user_state:

        queryset = User.objects.filter(full_name__icontains=full_name,
                                       email__icontains=email,
                                       facility_name__icontains=facility_name,
                                       user_state__icontains=user_state) \
            .annotate(facility=F('facility_name'),
                      state=F('user_state'),
                      last_access=F('lastAccess')) \
            .order_by('-id').distinct()

    else:
        queryset = User.objects.all()\
            .annotate(facility=F('facility_name'),
                      state=F('user_state'),
                      last_access=F('lastAccess'))\
            .order_by('-id')

    return queryset
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more `some records that I expect to have been selected are not selected` ?
What's not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. First, let me advice that such filtering should be done in the `filter_queryset` method and not `get_queryset` method or better off, use the [DjangoFilterBackend from django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) which is the common practice.

Now pertaining your code, you add the filters even when they are not specified. Assuming the client has added the query param `full_name=foo`, your code goes on to add `email="",facility_name="",user_state=""` to the filter which will most likely not return anything as there will be no combination of those values in the database. So rather, than doing that, add only the query params specified.

Something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    filter_fields = ['full_name', 'email', 'facility_name', 'user_state']

    params = {'{}__icontains'.format(k): v for k,v in self.request.query_params.items() if k in filter_fields}

    queryset = User.objects.filter(**params) \
                .annotate(facility=F('facility_name'),
                          state=F('user_state'),
                          last_access=F('lastAccess')) \
                .order_by('-id').distinct()

    return queryset
```

Again, you should consider moving this to `filter_queryset` as that is the method meant for filtering.